# Positioning two elements inside wrapper element

Tags: css, positioning

I'm having a few problems trying to position two divs, side-by-side, inside a wrapper div, one with left align and the other with right align.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="member_top" style="padding:15px; background:#DDD;">
    <div class="member_top_wrap" style="width:960px; margin:0 auto; position:relative;">
        <div class="member_top_left" style="display:inline-block; width:480px;">Left</div>
        <div class="member_top_right" style="display:inline-block; width:480px;">Right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried adding position relative to the `member_top_wrap` and absolute on the two inside elements, using left and right positioning, but then the 15px padding wasn't working. Can somebody please explain how to achieve this?

This is an illustrated example:

[image]

I'm not looking for the padding in between the two elements as shown in the illustration, I added the gap to define the two elements.

Comment: Float one left and the other right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply float the divs and then clear the bottom of the floats,

```
<div class="member_top" style="padding:15px; background:#DDD; width: 960px;">
<div class="member_top_wrap" style="margin:0 auto; position:relative;">
    <div class="member_top_left" style="display:inline-block; width:480px;float: left;">Left</div>
    <div class="member_top_right" style="display:inline-block; width:480px;float: left;">Right</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/6dgSF/1/)

As a side note... you really don't want to do this with inline styles. A stylesheet is much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, I do write my CSS in external stylesheets. Because I'm new to CSS layouts, moving away from tables, I tend to design a part of my page with inline styles, as it's quicker to get things wrong :) When I have it right, I copy the styles to my external stylesheet, cleaning up my code.

Answer (score 0):

check this link
http://jsfiddle.net/bbmG6/1/

```
.member_top_wrap{
    width:960px;
    padding:15px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
}
    .member_top_left{
    float:left;
    width:480px;
    background:yellow;
}
.member_top_right{
    float:right;
    background:green;
    width:480px;
}​
```

Comment: I didn't down-vote this, I have no idea why somebody would, and it annoys me when people can't be bothered to explain why. However, I didn't accept your answer because where you used float:left on .member_top_wrap, it caused some problems with .member_top and its parent container.

Comment: I will up-vote this back to 0 for you, as you were kind enough to write a good answer with a demo.

Comment: @PraveenVijayan i down vote you because you css explanation is wrong. If there is a float in the child elements them give overflow:hidden to it's a parent to clear it instead of giving float to it which is wrong check this for more http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: martin - thanks. @sandeep - thanks for the explanation for "why down voted". But, there is nothing wrong when if you give float:left to its parent container to clear float, if you are sure about what would be the effect of  that float. Overflow method will create problem in some situations (both auto & hidden). Lot of ways to clear a float.  I'm using clearfix to do this job. Since I have no idea about the other elements in martin's page I put forth a solution. The answer is not deserve for a down vote. But my solution is  is not suited for martin.

Answer (score -1):

When using `display: inline-block`, whitespace between `inline-block` elements turns into gap between elements. To get rid of this gap, set `font-size` for wrapper to `0`, and then restore `font-size` for child elements (usually with hard 'px' value, but for more latest browsers 'rem' [root em] can be used too).

Or remove whitespace between elements:

```
<div class="member_top_wrap"
    ><div class="member_top_left"></div
    ><div class="member_top_right"></div
></div>
```

Or just use `display: table` for wrapper and `display: table-cell` for its child elements.

Comment: This isn't what I asked for, sorry, think you got wrong end of the stick.